# Why is my phase difference so off?

Tags: waves

I've got two sine waves whose arguments differ only by a phase difference I'm calling `phi`. I'm trying to reverse engineer this phi from the sine waves I've created.

To do so, I'm finding the first peak of each wave. I'm then taking the inverse sine at that point on each wave to get my two angles. I then subtract them, expecting that I'll get back `phi`, but I do not. Why is that?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

f = 3
sample_rate = 100
phi = np.pi / 4  # phase difference

t = np.arange(0, 1, 1 / sample_rate)
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)
y2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t + phi)

ix1, _ = signal.find_peaks(y1)
ix2, _ = signal.find_peaks(y2)

theta1 = np.arcsin(y1[ix1[0]])
theta2 = np.arcsin(y2[ix2[0]]) 

print((theta1 - theta2, phi))
```

This yields a phase difference of `-0.03141592653589953` which is definitely not close to pi / 4. Am I misunderstanding what "phase" or "phase difference" means?

Comment: Your answer is pi/100, so look for some kind of interference from the sample rate.

Comment: @DavidWhite what do you mean by interference?

Comment: The fact that your phase difference is off by a factor of 100 strongly implies that your division by the sample rate is affecting the result you are looking for.

Comment: It is much worse than that. You are thinking you are getting the location of the angle on the x-axis at which you have peaks, and then subtracting them. But what your code actually does is that you found the numerical heights y of the peaks, taking their standard argsin, which necessarily always gives you nearly pi/2, except maybe displaced by your sampling rate failing to land exactly on the peak itself. That is why the subtraction you did, of two values slightly displaced off pi/2, is related to the sample rate. The logic of what you want to do is incompatible with the actual coded logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the `arcsin` on each peak - which gives you of course about the same value. In order to get the phase difference, you need to evaluate the `arcsin` on the *same time* for both time series - and then compare the difference you get there:

```
theta1 = np.arcsin(y1[ix1[0]])
theta2 = np.arcsin(y2[ix1[0]])
```

Not to evaluate each angle at the same time `ix1` (or use `ix2`, if you like, doesn't matter).

Then the result of your print statement is `(0.7853981633974481, 0.7853981633974483)`

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Because the values at the peak are the same, of course the arcsin would give the same value... stupid me, always over-complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

You are computing the phase angle at the peak, which should be pi/2. The difference is due to numerical resolution in the abscissa.

Rather, you need to convert the indices from find_peaks into time stamps, which can then be converted in a phase, since the angular frequency is the time derivative of phase.

Per questions in comments:

If:

$$ y(t) = \sin{\omega t + \phi_0} $$

the peaks occur for positive $y$ with

$$ \dot y(t) = \omega\cos{\omega t + \phi} = 0$$

Or

$$ \omega t + \phi = 0 $$
$$ t_{max} = -\phi/\omega $$

(Note, the last line converts between time and phase).

In your code, you plug that back into $y$ to get:

$$ y(t_{\max}) = \sin(\omega(-\phi/\omega) + \phi)  = \sin 0 $$

Then the arcsin is 1, regardless of $\phi$

That you have a sample rate of 100 and $\omega=6\pi$ leads to a numerical error of $\pi/100$.

I would simplify the problem and write the functions as:

$$ y_1 = \sin\phi_1(t) $$
$$ y_2 = \sin\phi_2(t) $$

with

$$ \phi_1(t) = \omega t $$
$$ \phi_2(t) = \omega t + \phi $$

My suggestion was to compute:

$$ \phi = \omega(t_2 - t_1) $$

from the peak times $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: Won't the angle at the peak entirely depend on the frequency of the wave? Why should it always be pi/2? 

Also can you clarify another thing... You say "the difference is due to numerical resolution", but the difference is off by a large factor (roughly 2)... The wave is well sampled at 100 Hz for a wave with a frequency of 3 hz... So I think resolution should be fine. Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Can you also expound on what it means to "convert" time stamps to a phase difference?